# Scope on multiple files and iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, windows-runtime

I have multipule files:

default.html

```
<script src="/js/global.js"></script>
<script src="/js/default.js"></script>
```

global.js:

```
var session_id=null;
```

default.js:

```
session_id = "stuffs";
console.log(session_id); //works
```

chatroom.html (iframe in default.html)

```
<script src="/js/global.js"></script>
<script src="/pages/chatroom/chatroom.js"></script>
```

chatroom.js:

```
console.log(session_id);//doesn't work. returns
```

How can I get access to session_id in chatroom.js? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following from within the iframe:

```
window.parent.session_id
```

also `window.top` should work if you have many nested iframes:

```
window.top.session_id
```